# Actionscript 3 Collision detection

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, physics, collision

I know there are some methods you can use like hittestPoint and so on, but I want to see where my movieclip colliedes with another another movieclip. Any other methods I can use?

by any chance does somebody know some a good introduction to game physics? Im asking because I coded a small engine and pretty much the whole code is spagetti code thats why I would like to know how you can setup something like this properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking at the physics libraries...

you have the popular choice: box2d ( http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/ ) or nape ( https://github.com/deltaluca/nape )

both of these include demos, which are a good place to start as most are meant for games

if you're doing 3d, then jiglib is a good place to look ( http://www.jiglibflash.com/ )

Comment: Haha thanks I acutally toyed around with these 2 libaries but looking into their as files is quite a smart idea =) btw I prefer nape

Comment: I think most agree that nape has better documentation. The last nape tests I've seen seem to put the performance above box2d.